# Is it possible to achieve this picture browsing effect with swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I tried to use the tabview, but the number of photos is too large, so I hope to load them dynamically, but when the tabview is dynamically modified, the screen will flicker, which is unacceptable.

Here is the effect I want:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                // We'll show the photo library in a grid
                
                TabView(selection: $imgIndex) {
                    ForEach(photoList.viewImageList, id: \.self) { index in
                        PhotoGridThumbnail(cacheIdList: $cacheIdList, currentIndex: $imgIndex ,assetLocalId: photoList.imgIdList[index].localIdentifier, index: index)
                            .environmentObject(photoList)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, alignment: .center)
                        .tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2), value: photoList.viewImageList)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height ,alignment: .center)
                .onChange(of: imgIndex, perform: {
                    newValue in
                    self.setupIndexRange(newValue: newValue)
                })
                .id(photoList.viewImageList)
     }
   }
```

Then in `self.setupIndexRange` , I change the `viewImageList` array, for example when swiping to the next photo, the code will append a new number of index in the array.

Comment: yes with animations you can achieve

Comment: Skip the tab view setup and create your own